# How to secure remote desktop?

Tags: ransomware, rdp

How to secure RDP connection to prevent the spread of ransomware from users' systems when they connect to corporate systems through remote desktop?

Comment: Here's a good read: https://security.berkeley.edu/education-awareness/securing-remote-desktop-rdp-system-administrators

Comment: Check out this tutorial from Fireeye: https://www.fireeye.com/content/dam/fireeye-www/current-threats/pdfs/wp-ransomware-protection-and-containment-strategies.pdf